# Where can I find blue screen of death crash dump?

Tags: windows-xp

Anyone guide me to find blue screen of death crash dump in windows XP?

Answer (score 5):

Try **C:\WINDOWS\Minidump**.  I've also been using the freeware BlueScreenView from Nirsoft, which parses the crash dump data and makes it easier to understand.

Refs:
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html

Comment: %windir% is more portable, is Windows is installed in some other partition/folder

Comment: @Sathya: I considered that, but the OP either knows enough to change the path to their own Windows folder, or they don't, in which case it's extremely unlikely that Windows is installed in any folder other than C:\WINDOWS.  Add to that the potential confusion as to what %windir% is (to anyone not familiar with that syntax), and I decided to keep things simple.  Next time I'll add the proviso: "or wherever Windows is installed on your machine".  Anyone else want to weigh in on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you can boot to safe mode it will be in your event viewer.

If it is automatically restarting and you can't read the message then turn off auto restart.

System Properties --> Advanced tab --> Startup and Recovery Settings --> uncheck "automatically restart"

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the Minidumps so that you can use [WhoCrashed](http://www.resplendence.com/whocrashed)? then it is available at `%windir%\minidump`